# Inserting data from an API into your database in symphony3

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

l am writing an application that makes a call to an api then returns some data. However l am stuck on populating the database with the data from the API. l tried looking through the decoded json array of object but that for some reason throws an error. my code is as below:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', API);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        $request = new Request();
        foreach ($data as $data) {
          $request->setName($data['name']);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($request);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('Saved new product with id '.$request->getId());
        return $this->render('ApiBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
```

For some reason the loop is not working. Is there a reason why this loop wont work and any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain, but in your for loop you are using '$data' twice. Instead should be (used $d instead):

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
   $request->setName($d['name']);
}
```

Also, you could try dumping $data to see what it contains.

Comment: Did my answer resolve the problem Kelvin? If so, click the "checkmark" as well. So when other people search they know this is the "correct" answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Alvin, it seems to be working now however putting the same item in the database everytime l hit the end point in my browser. any idea why?

Comment: Not sure I understand what's going on in your code Kelvin. You may want to try using `print_r`, described in these docs(http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), to dump the `$data` array. Maybe that will help you out. Also, Twig has a dump function. You use it like: `{{ dump(var) }}`